# How to dynamically create text boxes on selection of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web development and I am developing a form in HTML using Bootstrap.So I have a div like below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Users</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></span>
    <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" >
          <option value=" " >Please select the number of users</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option >3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So depending on the selection of number I want to dynamically create the text box like below div.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example if he selects 1 then one text box should appear if selects 2 then 2 should appear.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('.selectpicker[name=state]').change(function() {
  var i = 0;
//$('.input-group').children('input').remove() *for reset the inbox on change*
  while (i < parseInt($(this).val())) {
    $('.input-group').append('<input name="phone" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" type="text">')
    i++;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Users</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i></span>
      <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker">
          <option value=" " >Please select the number of users</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option >3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It adds text boxes but does not rest when I change to a new number.For example if I click 3 three box appears but if I click 1 again it keeps adding (3+1) and shows 4 text boxes.

Comment: Still behaves the same it seems

Comment: Yes I did not uncomment the resetting part.Thanks a lot

Comment: One quick question how do I set the selectpicker to the name "state"?

Comment: already the `name='state'` in the html or you need to use within js try `$('.selectpicker').attr('name','state')` .I think  you need place of js selector click function use like this `$('.selectpicker[name="state"]').click()` .choose as your wish

Comment: Yeah I did by `$('.selectpicker[name=state]').` Thanks again